# Vuetify only displaying first message on an input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

https://codepen.io/astannard/pen/WNRYmGo

```
<div id="app">
   <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-text-field
          label="Main input"
          :messages=['ahhhhhhh','haaaaaaaa']   
          hide-details="auto"
      ></v-text-field>
   </v-app>
</div>
```

I have the above code which uses vuetify, the issue is that only 'ahhhhhhhh' gets shown, ideally I would like 'haaaaaaaa' to be shown on the line below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `error-count` prop to 2:

```
<v-text-field
    label="Main input"
    :messages=['ah','ha'] 
    error-count=2
    hide-details="auto"
></v-text-field>
```

Result:

[image]